# How to get a Twitter users' expanded website url from t.co link?

Tags: php, api, twitter

I created a simple Twitter app using its API by following this [tutorial](http://iag.me/socialmedia/build-your-first-twitter-app-using-php-in-8-easy-steps/). What I want is to get basic Twitter user details/data such as name, website, description from his/her twitter profile using the API. 
The following code gets most of the details :

```
    <?php
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');
/** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
$settings = array(
'oauth_access_token' => "YOUR_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN",
'oauth_access_token_secret' => "YOUR_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET",
'consumer_key' => "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY",
'consumer_secret' => "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
);
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";
$requestMethod = "GET";
if (isset($_GET['user']))  {$user = $_GET['user'];}  else {$user  = "iagdotme";}
if (isset($_GET['count'])) {$count = $_GET['count'];} else {$count = 1;}
$getfield = "?screen_name=$user&count=$count";
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
if($string["errors"][0]["message"] != "") {echo "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3><p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>".$string[errors][0]["message"]."</em></p>";exit();}
foreach($string as $items)
    {
        echo "Tweeted by: ". $items['user']['name']."<br />";
        echo "Screen name: ". $items['user']['screen_name']."<br />";
        echo "Website: ". $items['user']['url']."<br />";
        echo "Listed: ". $items['user']['listed_count']."<br /><hr />";
    }
?>
```

The trouble is the link that it prints on **'Website' is a t.co link** which redirects to the website url the twitter user has mentioned on his profile. Instead of that I want to print the actual url(not t.co).

**What I've done till now**

I tried to expand the t.co using [this function](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/05/expand-short-url-using-php.html) but it instead of a result it display 'Array'. Is there any other way to get the actual web URL?

Comment: What does `print_r($headers)` show?

Comment: Haven't tried yet.Where should I place it? In the URL expand function?

Comment: Yes, right after you get the headers. Do that and make sure the "location" header is there and is as you'd expect it. Otherwise you may need to improvise (it's likely there are changes in HTTP 1.1 in this aspect, that function you are using is 6 years old at this point).

Comment: Alright. I did that. I do see that there is 'location' in there as well just like in any other short URL & it points to that actual location of the url. [Check the output here](http://pastebin.com/SGHYkGG2)

Comment: Keys are case sensitive so you may need to do `return $headers['location'];` in that function The `$headers["Location"]` has an array of 2 (identical) entries.

Comment: Oh Man! that was all, it works now. Thanks :-)